# Spring JDBCTemplate and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-data

I have a Spring, Spring Data, JPA/Hibernate application.
The legacy part of the application uses `JdbcTemplate` the new stuff uses spring-data/hibernate and everything is wrapped in a transaction.
Problem is when I modify an entity via hibernate and the legacy part of the system attempts to query something that's been modified I don't get the updated values with out having to explicitly "flush" the entity manager each time.
Is it possible execute the `JdbcTemplate` queries against hibernate's first-level cache?

What about trying this?
Edit: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html
This transaction manager also supports direct `DataSource` access within a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource). This allows for mixing services which access JPA and services which use plain JDBC (without being aware of JPA)! Application code needs to stick to the same simple `Connection` lookup pattern as with `DataSourceTransactionManager` (i.e. `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(javax.sql.DataSource)` or going through a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`). Note that this requires a vendor-specific `JpaDialect` to be configured.

Comment: If the update/save is not flushed, then it's dirty. You shouldn't perform operations on it.

Comment: No, it's not possible.